# I can't get the complex json data to the listview in flutter

Tags: json, list, listview, flutter, dart

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/9FwNMbDxKs/ this is my json data

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/yycQdpsHHM/ this is my model

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/wKgnfXy9tF/ this is my function in apiservice till now everything is fine but when i try to reach my json data like :

```
List<Menu> menuler = List<Menu>();


@override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    islemDonus = IslemDonus();

    islemDonus.anaMenuListeyiAl().then((value) {

      menuler.add(value[0].anagrupBaslik.toString());
      for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
        menuler.add(value[i].anagrupBaslik.toString());
      }
    });
```

it says:

```
The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Menu'.
```

but the value which comes from json data is Menu and as you can see i created my List why it is happening ?,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pyth0nGh057's answer is correct, but this might help your problem: https://medium.com/flutter-community/parsing-complex-json-in-flutter-747c46655f51

Comment: List<Menu> menu = List<Menu>();

void initState() {
    cekLogin();
    super.initState();
    menu = List<Menu>();
    islemDonus = IslemDonus();
    islemDonus.anaMenuListeyiAl().then((gelenDeger) {
      menu = gelenDeger;
    });
  }

it works good, thank by the way

Answer (score 0):

The method `toString` returns a `String`, so in your `menuler.add(value[i].anagrupBaslik.toString());` you are clearly adding a `String` into a `Menu` list.